# How to reconnect to a up vagrant box

Tags: vagrant, vagrant-windows

This is probably a really simple question - but after I have run vagrant up, and connected to the box via SSH etc - if I close the terminal, how can i reconnect to the instance?

Any command do if I have done this seems to fail, seemingly as it is running but I am not attached to that instance in the terminal?
Is there some sort of "rejoin/reconnect" command?

I am on Windows 10 using cmder if that helps?

Thanks in advance! =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can run `vagrant global-status`, check the `id` of the VM that you want to connect and run `vagrant ssh <vm_id>` it will ssh into the VM you want